# How can I add the column dynamically in SSIS from the csv file

Tags: sql, ssis, etl

My requirement is in the file1  have two columns say Name, Age and in the file 2 have  3 columns say Name, Age, Country. How to create a table dynamically based on the files in SSIS. Do i need to use script component?

Comment: Yes using C# Script component would work probably the best.  You can iteration through the file and column headers and dynamically create them in a temp/stage table.  Then import into that table.

Comment: Help me understand, what column is dynamically added? You have two sources that you need to match, seemingly based on Name. The output would be 4 columns, unless you need to have the match key, Name, repeated.

Comment: Yes Name is repeated in both the file sources. In this case how can I  proceed further